# How can I read / write a highscore from / to shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am writing a game and it needs to record the player's highscore and other info using `SharedPrefernces`. Here is my code to record the highscore, in Activity A

```
if (score > highcore) {
    highscore = score;
    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).editor().putInt("highscore", score);
}
```

And then, in Activity B I read the highscore and output it in a `TextView`.

```
textView.setText ("Highscore:" + Integer.toString(getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt ("highscore", 0)));
```

However, the output is 0.
I thought it is because the two calls to `putInt` and `getInt` are in different activities. So I put a breakpoint in one of Activity A's methods and use the "Evaluate Expression" button to evaluate `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt ("highscore", 0)` but it stills says it's 0. Why?

I think this has something to do with `MODE_PRIVATE`? If I cannot use `MODE_PRIVATE`, what *can* I use?

Comment: You never called `apply()` or `commit()`

Comment: better write it to db, using file operations is much costlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to commit:

```
    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).editor().putInt("highscore", score).commit();
```

In addition, as docs say about getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE):

> This simply calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

So you read another Prefernce file in Activity B.

instead you can use:

```
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("highscore", score).commit();
```

And read it back in Activity B:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("highscore", score);
```

Comment: What does `commit()` do?

Comment: `commit(): Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
         SharedPreferences object it is editing`

Comment: `apply(): Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
         SharedPreferences object it is editing. Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory`

Comment: @yshahak So if I want to read preferences I use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("highscore", score);`?

Answer (score 0):

All changes you make in an editor are **batched**, and not copied back to the original `SharedPreferences` until you call `commit()` or `apply()`.

You can use:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("highscore", score).commit();
```

Actually `commit()` writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add  `editor.commit();` or `editor.apply();` when storing the data to preferences..